# mockReturnValue always returns undefined after function call in jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

In my angular application i am writing unit test using `jest`. My component class name is `OrderViewComponent` which is like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getOrder()
}


public async getOrder(): Promise<void>{
   this.order$ = this.orderService.getOrder(this.orderId).pipe(
     tap((order: Order) => {
       this.order = order;
       this.isShowOrderDetails = !!this.order?.orderInvoiceIssued;
     })
   )
}
```

And my unit test is like this

```
describe('get:getOrder', () => {
  it('works', async () => {
    const mockedOrder = {id: 1, amount: 4000, orderInvoiceIssued: 'issued'}
    jest.spyOn(component['orderService'], 'getOrder').mockReturnValue(of(mockedOrder));

    await component.getOrder();
    console.log(component.order);
    expect(component.isShowOrderDetails).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Now, the problem is that this test is failing everytime.

Result:

```
Expected: true
Received: false
```

The issue is that the function `getOrder` in `ngOnInit` is getting called but the code block inside of `tap` is not getting executed because it's not subscribed anywhere. It's using `async` in the html template. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you mock the `orderService.getOrder` method correctly? Try debug it

Comment: @LinDu I updated the question, can you please have a look at it again. The problem is that in `getOrder` value is saving in observable variable `this.order$` and after that tap is happening. So what in debugging it is found that when `getOrder` function is getting called from `ngOnInit` so the code block inside `tap` is not executing. The reason for this is `getOrder` function is not subscribed anywhere. It's using in templarte with `async` pipe. So i have to deal this scenario